# iPhone, addSubView doesn't call willViewAppear?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm adding a view with `-addSubView`. I'm also using the view elsewhere and `presentModalViewController`.

`-viewWillAppear` is called with presentModalViewController but not with addSubView.

No doubt this is something obvious ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`viewWillAppear:` is called by the parent view controller when it presents another view controller (e.g. by `pushViewController:animated:` or `presentModalViewController:animated:`). It is never called when you manually call `addSubview:`.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer does not appear to be correct, in iOS 6.1 anyway.  When I create a view with a controller like this:

```
    self.welcomeController = [[DPLWelcomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DPLWelcomeViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.welcomeController.view.frame = self.window.screen.applicationFrame;
    self.welcomeController.delegate = self;
    [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:self.welcomeController.view];
```

-viewWillAppear *does* get called (as long as self.welcomeController is a strong property).

On the other hand, when I did it like this:

```
    DPLWelcomeViewController *welcomeController = [[DPLWelcomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DPLWelcomeViewController" bundle:nil];
    welcomeController.view.frame = self.window.screen.applicationFrame;
    welcomeController.delegate = self;
    [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:welcomeController.view];
```

ARC cleaned it up once this method exited, and as best I can tell, -viewWillAppear got sent to nil. (Notwithstanding that I could see the Welcome view on my screen -- I believe rootViewController.views retained the *view*, but nothing was retaining the *viewController*.)